# Auto insert dash in cell value after Input

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate adding dashes to cell value after user input, but every time i test the code, my excel restarts after the error is displayed. What is wrong with this code?

what i want to achieve is inserting dashes after every 3 char
`abc123abcde =abc-123-abc-de`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Selection.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Intersect(Range("a2:a100"), Target) Is Nothing Then
DLen = Len(Target)

If DLen < 10 Then
Target = Left(Target, 2) & "-" & Right(Target, 4)

ElseIf DLen > 10 Then
'do nothing
MsgBox "more 10"
End If

Target.NumberFormat = "@"

Application.EnableEvents = False
Target = DateV
Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `Target = Left(...` should be `DateV = Left(...`

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below - this at least won't crash. I think VBA is running into issues with DateV when the entered value is not a date. I also split out the writing into its own function to make sure there is not an infinite event loop. Your goal is a little unclear, because your example text "abc123abcde" is over 10 characters and will call the msg box. If you are trying to generate date formats then you're going to need more error handling and parsing aparatus to allow users to enter non-standard formats. If you literally just want to add a dash every 3rd letter then suggest using a loop like 'for i = 1 to len(target)'

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Kill
If Selection.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Intersect(Range("a2:a100"), Target) Is Nothing Then
DLen = Len(Target)

If DLen < 10 Then
TargetVal = Left(Target, 2) & "-" & Right(Target, 4)

ElseIf DLen > 10 Then
'do nothing
MsgBox "more 10"
End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
Call WriteDateV(Target, TargetVal)
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End If

Kill:
Exit Sub

End Sub

Private Sub WriteDateV(TargCell As Range, TargetVal As Variant)
On Error GoTo Kill

Application.EnableEvents = False

TargCell.Value = TargetVal
TargCell.NumberFormat = "@"

Application.EnableEvents = True

Kill:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```